# Ubuntu 18.04 error on waking up from sleep : Read-error on swap device

Tags: xorg, suspend, 18.04, ram, swap

After the laptop has been in sleep mode for a couple of hours,when I try and resume my session I get the following error:

> Read-error on swap device

It takes about 30 seconds for the login screen to load post this happening. Once I log in, the screen blanks out once or twice for a second, and none of my programs are open anymore. I get a "System problem detected" prompt. When I click on "Send Report", another notification pops up saying:

> Sorry the program "Xorg" closed unexpectedly. Your computeer does not have enough free memory to automatically analyze the problem and send a report to the developers.

What I have tried so far is to increase the swap space available. It was around 2 GB initially and I created another swap file of 9 GB. This hasn't helped. The occupied swap space ( as per the swapon command ) after the crash is always around 170MB.

The DMESG for when I resume my session, up to the read error on swap device is as follows:

```
    
[64046.474054] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[64046.474162] ACPI: EC: EC started
[64046.474162] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[64046.475139] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[64046.475196] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[64046.475196] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[64046.475663]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[64046.475859] CPU1 is up
[64046.475910] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[64046.476330]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[64046.476506] CPU2 is up
[64046.476539] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[64046.477071]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[64046.477255] CPU3 is up
[64046.477274] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[64046.477721]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
[64046.477922] CPU4 is up
[64046.477947] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[64046.478371]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
[64046.478571] CPU5 is up
[64046.478591] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[64046.479018]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
[64046.479229] CPU6 is up
[64046.479247] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[64046.479675]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
[64046.479899] CPU7 is up
[64046.485913] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[64046.639206] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[64046.639711] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[64046.873289] usb 1-11: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[64046.976869] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[64046.976892] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[64047.149289] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd
[64047.437370] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5660], y [..4570]
[64047.476302] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1364..], y [1284..]
[64047.922603] OOM killer enabled.
[64047.922605] Restarting tasks ... done.
[64047.928727] thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[64047.930036] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[64047.935036] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[64047.935037] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[64047.935038] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[64047.935038] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[64047.935039] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[64047.935040] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[64047.935042] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[64047.944372] PM: suspend exit
[64048.050329] Read-error on swap-device (8:0:1543400288)
[64048.460888] [drm] RC6 on
```

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem - after upgrading to 18.04, closing the laptop lid results in the same error message (Read error on swap device) and a reboot. If you manage to find a fix elsewhere it would be great if you could share it here.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. I did some research and [users on arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235027]) were having the same problem a couple of months ago and concluded it probably has something to do with the 4.15 kernel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ubuntu 18.04 kernel you are currently using is missing a rather important bug fix.

The fix for this is already present in the upstream Linux kernel version 4.16.8.  (The suspend bug effectively started happening in kernel version 4.15).  Ubuntu only needs to cherry-pick this small patch from upstream.  The bug frequently causes Xorg crashes immediately after suspend, i.e. it crashes the whole graphical login session.

Note this bug often happens *without* showing `Read-error on swap device`. Most of the time, there was no error in the kernel log.  (A few times, it showed `EXT4-fs error` and `Buffer I/O error` instead).  Also, these error messages could be caused by a hardware failure instead.  When diagnosing this problem, please focus on other, more distinct details.

A test kernel is available at the end of this Ubuntu bug, i.e. in this comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1776887/comments/5

So far no-one has reported their results from suspending with the Ubuntu test kernel.  <del>It might be that if someone can report success, it will encourage the Ubuntu developer to finally include the bug fix.  I could be wrong though, I'm not 100% sure what's holding this up.</del>

There is also a known workaround.  You can avoid the crash if you configure the kernel command line to include the option `scsi_mod.scan=sync`.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1776887

---

> This upstream bug has been confirmed to affect Ubuntu users[1]. As per
>   the fix commit (below), the most frequent symptom is a crash of
>   Xorg/Xwayland, i.e. killing the entire GUI, when a laptop is woken
>   from system sleep. Frequency of the bug is described as once every few
>   days[2].
>
> [1] E.g. this user confirms the bug & very specific workaround:
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1760450/comments/11
>
> [2] E.g. this log of crashes:
>   https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1553979#c23
>
> This is a bug in blk-core.c. It is not specific to any one hardware
>   driver. Technically the suspend bug is triggered by the SCSI core -
>   which is used by *all SATA devices*.
>
> The commit also includes a test which quickly and reliably proves the
>   existence of a horrifying bug.
>
> I guess you might avoid this bug only if you have root on NVMe. The
>   other way to not hit the Xorg crash is if you don't use all your RAM,
>   so there's no pressure that leads to cold pages of Xorg being swapped.
>   Also, you won't reproduce the Xorg crash if you suspend+resume
>   immediately. (This frustrated my tests at one point, it only triggered
>   after left the system suspended over lunch :).
>
> Fix: "block: do not use interruptible wait anywhere"
>
> in kernel 4.17:
>   https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1dc3039bc87ae7d19a990c3ee71cfd8a9068f428
>
> in kernel 4.16.8:
>   https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?h=linux-4.16.y&id=7859056bc73dea2c3714b00c83b253d4c22bf7b6
>
> lack of fix in 4.15.0-24.26 (ubuntu 18.04):
>   https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic/tree/block/blk-core.c?id=Ubuntu-4.15.0-24.26#n856
>
> I.e., this bug is still present in Ubuntu source package
>   linux-4.15.0-24.26 (and 4.15.0-23.25). I attach hardware details
>   (lspci-vnvn.log) of a system where this bug is known to happen.
>
> Regards Alan
>
> WORKAROUND: Use kernel parameter: scsi_mod.scan=sync

Comment: Excellent work around! Confirmed on Ubuntu 18.04 w/ 4.15 kernel.

Comment: Actually this didn't work after a second test.

Comment: @ricosrealm most unexpected. Please confirm your issue is (sometimes) manifesting as SIGBUS (signal number 7) in Xorg or gnome-shell. This is easy if you have `systemd-coredump` installed and use `coredumpctl -r`, but I don't know what to do when you have apport installed.  (systemd-coredump and apport packages conflict with each other, please exercise judgement).

Comment: @ricosrealm But at least I can ask you to confirm that 1) your current graphical session goes away, but the system remains otherwise usable and you can log back in again 2) `dmesg` does *not* show a "segfault" message for Xorg / gnome-shell.  (And most commonly I din't see any kernel errors, but you might see "Read-error on swap device" some of the time).

Comment: @ricosrealm Btw, the patch seems to have made a bit more progress since I posted the answer. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2018-June/093612.html

Comment: You might be able to check Xorg logs, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` / `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` / `$HOME/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log.old` etc, they might confirm a crash with a "Bus error" message.

Comment: ah, I mean Xorg or Xwayland - not gnome-shell.  Sorry.

Comment: The other kernel errors in `dmesg` that this sometimes triggers are "EXT4-fs error" or "Buffer I/O error".

Comment: @ricosrealm  Or, there's a quick way to cross-check the workaround: have you tried the test command mentioned in the commit? You should find it reliably shows an IO error if you don't have the workaround, and reliably doesn't show an IO error if you have the workaround.  It's a complex shell command that needs root, so run it from inside `sudo -i`.  https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2018-June/093605.html

Comment: This did not solve my issue, although it seemed to make it better.  I don't see anything about swap space, but in syslog I do see several errors: "fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"" from multiple apps

Comment: there are a ton of messages, I also see something about "(EE) modeset(G0): failed to set mode: No space left on device" and "(EE) EnterVT failed for gpu screen 0".  I don't have any devices that are low on space though...