# Kubuntu 18.04 suspend function is really buggy and problematic consistently

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, suspend

I'm having serious issues with Kubuntu's suspend functionality.

If I let the computer suspend by itself it tends to never wake up when I try to resume the system, and I only will see a blank screen, forcing me to restart. if initiate suspend from the Kicker menu, I no longer see the suspend/shutdown/hibernate buttons and 30 second warning that go along with it pop up, and the vast majority of the time I am logged out when I suspend, forcefully terminating many important applications such as libreoffice (I am in the process of writing a book and it feels more and more by the day that all these bugs are gonna totally corrupt and destroy my drafts. It worries me severely).

Specs:
Asus M5A78L-M Plus motherboard,
Asus GTX 460 1gb with the most current drivers
AMD FX-6300 six core processor
6gb DDR3 RAM (The ram is somewhat old but I did a RAM test as recently as a few months ago with no errors perceived by GRUB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a particular known issue on Ubuntu 18.04, which I think matches everything you describe.

Suspending on Ubuntu 18.04 may sometimes cause X, and hence your entire graphical session to crash.  The issue is described, along with a work-around, in my answer to this question:

[Ubuntu 18.04 error on waking up from sleep : Read-error on swap device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device/1050201#1050201)