# Restarts after waking from sleep on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend, hibernate

So far a number of times i faced this issue that the Ubuntu kind of restarts after opening it from sleep. While i expect it resumes the previously opened applications it show an empty desktop with no application at all.

I found a similar issue on the [dell community forum](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Suspend-resume-problems-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/6072410), but i do not have any Nvidia device.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell laptop. Previously i was using Ubuntu 16.04 with no issue at all. 
How to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this sleep or hibernate? Just want to get clarification as you tagged hibernate in the keyword list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 error on waking up from sleep : Read-error on swap device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device). For most people that should kick them back to the login screen though. I wonder if you have configured auto-login?

Answer (score 0):

I reset the BIOS Setting on my XPS 13 and it worked! Don't forget to set the Drive options back on AHCI instead of RAID