# on resume from suspend I am logged out (18.10)

Tags: suspend, logout

I have a fresh 18.10 install (not an upgrade) which ran fine for days
now when I suspend then resume it has logged me out ...
This behavior is repeatable ... every suspend results in a resume into a fresh login session.
My uptime indicates its not a reboot just a log out

Does not appear to be a dupe of [Ubuntu 18.04 error on waking up from sleep : Read-error on swap device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device)

here is my `dmesg`

```
[26608.984186] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[26609.000454] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[26609.021691] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[26611.124524] wlp2s0: authenticate with 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f
[26611.131872] wlp2s0: send auth to 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (try 1/3)
[26611.138863] wlp2s0: authenticated
[26611.139067] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[26611.139069] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[26611.146696] wlp2s0: associate with 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (try 1/3)
[26611.149328] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[26611.152190] wlp2s0: associated
[26611.180321] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[26621.901198] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[26621.916075] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[26621.935734] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[26623.176050] rfkill: input handler disabled
[27152.084848] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[29289.263525] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[29289.321673] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[29289.321675] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[29298.783766] rfkill: input handler enabled
[29299.075220] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.005 seconds) done.
[29299.081055] OOM killer disabled.
[29299.081056] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[29299.083226] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[29299.103284] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[29299.161935] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[29300.169199] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[29300.221949] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[29300.226223] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[29300.226224] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[29300.226226] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[29300.226348] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[29300.239384] IRQ 132: no longer affine to CPU1
[29300.240400] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[29300.263319] IRQ 129: no longer affine to CPU2
[29300.264341] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[29300.295256] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU3
[29300.295271] IRQ 130: no longer affine to CPU3
[29300.296301] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[29300.303275] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[29300.303354] ACPI: EC: EC started
[29300.303355] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[29300.305660] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[29300.305708] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[29300.305708] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[29300.306214]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[29300.306334] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x38
[29300.307835] CPU1 is up
[29300.307892] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[29300.308411]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[29300.308502] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x8e
[29300.308606] CPU2 is up
[29300.308633] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[29300.309114]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[29300.309317] CPU3 is up
[29300.313109] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[29300.323688] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[29300.366900] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[29300.370092] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[29300.662986] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[29300.939113] usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[29301.214978] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[29302.084494] ish-hid {33AECD58-B679-4E54-9BD9-A04D34F0C226}: [hid-ish]: enum_devices_done OK, num_hid_devices=2
[29302.203528] usb 1-1: reset low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[29302.548544] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[29302.548785] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[29302.549013] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[29302.549243] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[29302.549469] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[29302.549694] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[29302.549919] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[29302.550146] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[29302.550372] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[29302.550595] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[29302.550859] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[29302.551082] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[29302.551304] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[29302.551526] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[29302.551756] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[29302.551980] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[29302.552203] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[29302.552425] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[29302.552647] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
[29302.552789] OOM killer enabled.
[29302.552791] Restarting tasks ... done.
[29302.559631] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[29302.564120] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[29302.571287] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[29302.571289] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[29302.571292] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[29302.571293] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[29302.571294] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[29302.571295] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[29302.571299] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[29302.586626] PM: suspend exit
[29302.718694] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[29302.924178] rfkill: input handler disabled
[29303.137427] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[29303.218213] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[29303.277237] Chrome_~dThread[31595]: segfault at 0 ip 00007faa0107614f sp 00007fa9f8a96ab0 error 6 in libxul.so[7fa9fd9e3000+4bac000]
[29303.277244] Code: 8b 0d 05 3d 62 03 48 89 01 c7 04 25 00 00 00 00 73 01 00 00 e8 52 66 97 fc 48 8d 05 06 b3 66 01 48 8b 0d e4 3c 62 03 48 89 01 <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 6d 0a 00 00 e8 31 66 97 fc 90 55 48 89 e5 41 
[29303.277713] Chrome_~dThread[31832]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fb8b0fda14f sp 00007fb8a89faab0 error 6 in libxul.so[7fb8ad947000+4bac000]
[29303.277717] Code: 8b 0d 05 3d 62 03 48 89 01 c7 04 25 00 00 00 00 73 01 00 00 e8 52 66 97 fc 48 8d 05 06 b3 66 01 48 8b 0d e4 3c 62 03 48 89 01 <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 6d 0a 00 00 e8 31 66 97 fc 90 55 48 89 e5 41 
[29303.279621] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[29303.305878] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[29303.320049] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[29303.494372] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[29303.559297] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[29303.623129] rfkill: input handler enabled
[29304.057065] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[29304.057601] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1466071 usecs
[29304.057611] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[29304.069678] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11789 usecs
[29304.069682] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[29304.073659] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[29304.508742] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[29304.536533] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[29304.555933] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[29306.976415] wlp2s0: authenticate with 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f
[29306.984290] wlp2s0: send auth to 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (try 1/3)
[29306.992232] wlp2s0: authenticated
[29306.992490] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[29306.992491] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[29306.994584] wlp2s0: associate with 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (try 1/3)
[29306.997426] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[29306.999970] wlp2s0: associated
[29307.023276] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[29318.243823] rfkill: input handler disabled
```